# Ruby on Rails counter cache error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, counter-cache

I get the error `Unknown key(s): counter_cache` when trying to implement a counter cache column in my RoR app.

I implemented the model associations in this question: [Model association question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342770/model-association-question/5343366#5343366)

Here's my migration:

```
class AddVideoVotesCountToVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :videos, :video_votes_count, :integer, :default => 0

    Video.reset_column_information
    Video.find(:all).each do |p|
      p.update_attributes :videos_votes_count, p.video_votes.length
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :videos, :video_votes_count
  end
end
```

However, after watching http://media.railscasts.com/videos/023_counter_cache_column.mov I thought that maybe I had to move `:counter_cache => true` into the VideoVote model after `belongs_to :video`. However, when I do that, I get the error:

`wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`update_attribute` not `update_attribteS`

```
p.update_attribute :videos_votes_count, p.video_votes.length
```

or with `update_attributes`:

```
p.update_attributes( :video_votes_count => p.video_votes.length )
```

**UPD 1**

`:counter_cache => true` should be at the VideoVote class:

```
class VideoVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Comment: still get the first error... where should `:counter_cache => true` go?

Comment: ok, now I get this error: `undefined method 'videos_votes_count=' for #<Video:0x10362a698>`

Comment: you use `update_attributes` or `update_attribute`? Also you can temprory remove `counter_cache => true` because it obviously locks field

Comment: What method do you use, which one `update_attributes` or `update_attribute` ? :) and remove `counter_cache => true` for a while, do your migrate  and return it back :)

Comment: ahh ok yeah, that solved it, I needed to take out counter_cache, migrate, and then return it back... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To do counter_caching,you need to run the migration first that fills in the count columns BEFORE you include the counter_cache statement in the model. Once in the model, the columns are read only.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid read-only errors while running this migration, you should use reset_counters:

```
Video.find_each do |video|
  Video.reset_counters video.id, :video_votes
end
```

Comment: The second argument to the `reset_counters` method needs to be the name of the association, not the name of the counter_cache column, so it should be: `Video.reset_counters video.id, :video_votes`

Comment: `reset_counters` is now deprecated

Comment: @gwho I think it's still there... https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb#L20

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting Rajive Jain's solution :

Remove `:counter_cache => true` statement from the model file.

Rerun the migration : `rake db:migrate`

Add the counter_cache statement in your model : `:counter_cache => true`